# Laravel / VS Code - How to command click to go to function definition

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I have tried installing all sorts of intellisense packages in vs code but nothing is making CMD + Click to go to function definition work. For example if I have some code:

```
[
 'username' => fake()->userName()
]

.... 

User::where('name', $name)->get();
```

And I try to CMD + Click `userName()` or `where()` or `get()` it doesn't do anything. If I try to right click it and `Go To Definition` it says "No definition found". Does anyone know how to get this to work? I've tried installing "Intelephanse", "Laravel Extra Intellisense" and "PHP IntelliSense".

Comment: Start with Intellephense by Felix Becker. Check your settings.json, sometimes, there's a setting that overruled your CTRL+click. For example the multiple cursors: I has to set that to the alt key to get CTRL+click to work: `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",` => `"editor.multiCursorModifier": "altCmd",` (or just '**alt**')

Comment: I have no idea about intellisense for VSCode, I do use PHPStorm + [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper), and that helper adds some definitions (`php artisan ide-helper:meta`) that only PHPStorm understands, and do relate these types of things like you want to do. The one "issue" with `faker()->method()`, is that `method()` does not really exist, it is based on magic keywords like [`__call`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call). If you do use `faker()->userName` it should be found, but do not do that

Comment: There are some memory leaks and other issues related to `faker`, and they will even give you a warning saying `do not call any stuff you want as a property: faker()->userName, call it as a method: faker()->userName(), that will prevent some known memory leaks`, that is why VSCode do not understand it, it is using PHPDocblocks to let intelligent enough IDEs to understand that `userName()` do exists even though it is not defined literally as `public function userName()`: https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/f85772abd508bd04e20bb4b1bbe260a68d0066d2/src/Faker/Generator.php#L7-L555

Comment: That last link I shared is the PHPDoc block that faker uses, it always gives you back a `Generator` class if I am not confused, and you can see it does implement `__call` (for any `faker()->method()` call) and `__get` (for any `faker()->property` call): https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/f85772abd508bd04e20bb4b1bbe260a68d0066d2/src/Faker/Generator.php#L943-L962. But the one telling your IDE what it has available is that huge PHPDoc block comment. VSCode is not reading it because it does not know that `faker()` returns a `Generator` instance.

Answer (score 0):

For the `fake()` I can't help you much.

**For the Models queries:**

TLDR; use the static method `query()` for the IDE to recognize Builder methods

```
User::query()->where('name', $name)->get();
```

Since calling `where()` statically passes through the magic method `__callStatic($method, $parameters)` the IDE has hard time to track it since it depends on runtime. But if you follow how the static call for `where()` is resolved you will see that it first call `$this->newQuery()` on a new instance, then foreward the rest of the method call which is equivalent to calling the static method `query()`.